# Open Graph user own created object issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm following the documentation here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-object-api/

Using the following:

```
/me/objects/<app-namespace>:<created-object>?privacy={"value":"SELF"}
&object={"image":"https://<image-url>"}&access_token=<user-token>
```

Testing with the Graph API tool i'm getting this error:

```
    {
      "error": {
        "message": "(#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions", 
        "type": "OAuthException", 
        "code": 200
      }
}
```

Ok well that seems obvious until I debug the access token:

```
Valid   True
Origin  Mobile Web Faceweb
Scopes  publish_actions, user_friends
```

Anyone else seen this or have an idea of how to fix it?

**EDIT** Ok so I had publish_actions in both User & Friends and Extended permissions. I removed the User & Friends permission and now I get this:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "An unknown error has occurred.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 1
  }
}
```

Me no like unknown.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so a couple things to note here that went wrong.

I picked an object type as an item thinking it would be `<myapp>:item` in the call. Well as it turns out the item is actually a product type so it is `product.item` a global type. What is handy is to actually click the get code link on the objects you create.  Solution was to actually create my own app object type, which I thought I had.

In the Graph API make sure you actually use the application pull down in the top right to select the right app. I noticed some issues when it was set to the generic Graph API Explorer app.

Silly mistakes but cost me some time, hope it helps someone else.